# Generate version ID of struct definition?

Tags: c, gcc, clang

Basically, what I want is some kind of compile-time generated version that is associated with the exact definition of a struct. If the definition of the struct changes in any way (field added, moved, *maybe* renamed), I want that version to change, too.

Such a version constant would be useful when reading in a previously serialized struct, to make sure that it's still compatible. The alternative would be manually keeping track of a manually specified constant, which has potentially confusing effects if incrementing it is forgotten (deserializing produces garbage), and also raises the question when exactly to increment it (during development and testing, or only during some kind of release).

This could be achieved by using an external tool to generate a hash over the struct definition, but I'm wondering if it is possible with the C compiler (and/or maybe its preprocessor) itself.

This is actually some form of introspection and so I suspect that this may not be possible at all in ANSI C, but I would be happy with a solution that works with gcc and clang.

Answer (score 2):

The Windows API used to (still does?) have a size member as one of the first members of a struct, so that it knew what version of the struct it was being passed (see [`WNDCLASSEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633577%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as an example):

```
struct Foo
{
    size_t size;
    char *bar;
    char *baz;
    /* Other fields */
};
```

And before calling you set the size using `sizeof`:

```
struct Foo f;

f.size = sizeof(struct Foo);
f.bar = strdup("hi");
f.baz = strdup("there");

somefunc(&f);
```

Then `somefunc` would know, based on the `size` member, which version of the struct it was dealing with.  Because `sizeof` is evaluated at compile time instead of run-time, this allows for backwards ABI compatibility.

Comment: Thanks. I thought about just using sizeof, but that of course does not guard against fields which are moved, or other operations that result in any previously seen size. For the Windows API, it's probably a good idea to restrict modifications to only additions of fields, but I currently don't really want to go that far...

Comment: @Julien the idea is to only add new fields and to deprecate the ones that need to be moved or modified. The issue is that it is no portable across different compilers / systems because padding and basic types width is implementation defined.

Comment: @ouah Yeah, I got that, but as I said I don't want to go the "fields may only be deprectated" route right now. I am also aware that this won't be portable, but there is currently no need to. (Nevertheless, a somewhat portable way is imaginable and would be even better.)

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing that would do it automatically, but you can build something that works reasonably reliably: you can use `sizeof` and `offsetof`, and combine them in such a way that the order in which you combine them mattered. Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

#define COMBINE2(a,b) ((a)*31+(b)*11)
#define COMBINE3(a,b,c) COMBINE2(COMBINE2(a,b),c)
#define COMBINE4(a,b,c,d) COMBINE2(COMBINE3(a,b,c),d)

typedef struct A {
    int a1;
    char a2;
    float a3;
} A;

typedef struct B {
    int b1;
    char b2;
    double b3;
} B;

typedef struct C {
    char c2;
    int c1;
    float c3;
} C;

typedef struct D {
    int d1;
    char d2;
    float d3;
    int forgotten[2];
} D;

int main(void) {
    size_t aSign = COMBINE4(sizeof(A), offsetof(A,a1), offsetof(A,a2), offsetof(A,a3));
    size_t bSign = COMBINE4(sizeof(B), offsetof(B,b1), offsetof(B,b2), offsetof(B,b3));
    size_t cSign = COMBINE4(sizeof(C), offsetof(C,c1), offsetof(C,c2), offsetof(C,c3));
    size_t dSign = COMBINE4(sizeof(D), offsetof(D,d1), offsetof(D,d2), offsetof(D,d3));
    printf("%ld %ld %ld %ld", aSign, bSign, cSign, dSign);
    return 0;
}
```

This code [prints](http://ideone.com/LSDFF)

```
358944 478108 399864 597272
```

As you can see, this code produces run-time constants for each structure that reacts to re-ordering of fields of different lengths and changing fields' types. It also reacts to adding fields even if you forget to update the list of fields on which you base your computation, which should produce some sort of a safety net.

Comment: Ah, I forgot about `offsetof`. I guess this is the closest thing possible with ANSI C?

Comment: @Julien Yes, I think you can't do much better than combining these two, at least within ANSI C. You can build a better `COMBINE`, though: mine looks like a quick and dirty work, although I use something like that in production code for hashing various structures.

Comment: @Julien If you do not have a restriction that the function must be computed at compile time, you could potentially guard against renaming by computing hash on strings that represent names of struct's fields (you'd need to use `#` preprocessor stringification operator for that).

Comment: Pity... although it may be worth a gcc/clang extension 8)